# Odoo : How to remove not null constraint from Odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-survey

I have to remove not null constraint from odoo not in postgresql.

Eg:

```
time_table_lines_1 = fields.One2many(
        'gen.time.table.line', 'gen_time_table', 'Time Table Lines',
        domain=[('day', '=', '1')], required=True)
```

I want to remove `required = True` from Odoo Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set required to `False` if you're extending an existing model

or omit it entirely if you're building a custom model that doesn't extend any existing model.

```
time_table_lines_1 = fields.One2many(
        'gen.time.table.line', 'gen_time_table', 'Time Table Lines',
        domain=[('day', '=', '1')], required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that keyword from that line.

```
time_table_lines_1 = fields.One2many('gen.time.table.line','gen_time_table', 'Time Table Lines',
    domain=[('day', '=', '1')])
```

Comment: He said `I want to remove required = True from Odoo Python.`. if it was so simple he would not ask at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
time_table_lines_1 = fields.One2many(
        'gen.time.table.line', 'gen_time_table', 'Time Table Lines',
        domain=[('day', '=', '1')], required=True)
```

Remove that keyword  `required=True` from that line.

and it will become

```
time_table_lines_1 = fields.One2many(
            'gen.time.table.line', 'gen_time_table', 'Time Table Lines',
            domain=[('day', '=', '1')])
```

Thanks

Abhay S

Comment: He said `I want to remove required = True from Odoo Python.`. if it was so simple he would not ask at all.